# .scrollTop to an element with fixed banner on top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I have figured out how to make scrollTop like this:

```
$("#nav-home").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#content-home").offset().top}, 800);
});
```

But my problem is that i have a fixed banner on top of screen so when it scrolls the page part of the `#content-home` element is hidden by the banner.

Also I am using this:

```
var hheight = $(".mainh").height();
var theight = hheight + 14;
$("#first-content").css("margin-top", mheight + "px")
```

to automatically add top margin depending on height of the banner + 2*7px border (+ 14). I know it's stupid but I'am happy with it working this way.

So I am asking for something like a way to add more to the offset. Or maybe add the offset of the first element affected by "the margin calculator" I've mentioned above.

If you could help me out with this and maybe even add some tips I'd be really happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not subtract the height of the banner to the `scrollTop` number?

```
var contentTop = $("#content-home").offset().top;
var hheight = $(".mainh").outerHeight(true); // the 'true' in the statement will include the top and bottom margin of the element, if they exist.
var scrollTopY = contentTop - hheight;

$("#nav-home").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollTopY}, 800);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me. But i had to replace "+ hheight" with "- hheight" for some reason when i had the + there it scrolled perfectly but to the next element after the content-home. I don't really know why this did that but I don't really care since it's working fine now.

Comment: @MasterTX you're right, of course, we should be subtracting the height of the header, not adding it! My answer has been edited to fix this ~

Answer (score 0):

use this

$('.mainh').outerHeight(true)